# pass inputbox value as a querystring to URL

Tags: jquery, url, query-string, inputbox

I have an inputbox and a link for `SEARCH` styled to look like a Search button. When a user types in a keyword in the inputbox, I want to grab that keyword, pass it, and append it as a search query string to the search URL

```
/search/pages/physicians.aspx?v=relevance&s=Physicians&k=
```

So if `Cardiologist` is the keyword, it would be like:

```
http://ABChospital.org/search/pages/physicians.aspx?v=relevance&s=Physicians&k=Cardiologist
```

How can I achieve this in jquery?

```
<input name="KeywordBox" class="BasicSearchInputBox" type="text" value="Enter Keywords.."/>
            <div class="searchBtnHolder"> 
             <a class="searchButton" href="/search/pages/physicians.aspx?v=relevance&s=Physicians&k=" type="submit"><span>
             Search</span></a>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a `<form>` with an `<input type="submit">` button? Is jQuery really necessary for this trivial HTML task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.searchButton').click(function() {
    location.href = this.href + $('.BasicSearchInputBox').val();
    return false;
});
```