# Pass inputbox text as querystring to url

Tags: jquery, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass inputbox value as a querystring to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387494/pass-inputbox-value-as-a-querystring-to-url)

```
<input name="KeywordBox" class="BasicSearchInputBox" type="text" value="Keywords.."/>
<a class="searchButton" href="/search/pages/Careers.aspx?v=relevance&s=Careers&k=" type="submit">
    <span>Search</span>
</a>
```

How do you get the keywords typed in by users and pass it to the page or append to the URL onclick of the 'Search' link?

Like this `http://mycompany.com/search/pages/Careers.aspx?v=relevance&s=Careers&k=engineer`

Using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is to place your inputs into a `form` and submit them to your page using the GET method.

If you'd prefer to use jQuery, you can do:

```
$(function() {
    $(".searchButton").click(function() {
        var keywords = $("#KeywordBox").val();
        window.location.assign("/search/pages/Careers.aspx?v=relevance&s=Careers&k=" + keywords);
    });
});
```

Just make sure you sanitise your input values properly otherwise you're leaving yourself open to injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** method

Comment: how do you use it though? I am new to jquery world ??

Comment: The hyperlink provides an example as well