# How to pass input field values as a url query string that will be opened on click of a submit button?

Tags: javascript, forms

I would have to input fields like this

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="XXX">
    <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="XXX">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

On click of the submit I would like to send them to a new page with the value of the input appended to the url with query string.

```
 http://www.link.com/page?keyword=XYXYX&state=XZXX
```

Here is my start thinking but was thinking `.serialize()` can handle this better than this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387494/pass-inputbox-value-as-a-querystring-to-url)

```
  var keywordVal = $("#keyword").val();
  var stateVal = $("#state").val();

  $( "form" ).on( "submit", function() {
   event.preventDefault();
   location.href='http://www.link.com/page?keyword=' + keywordVal + '&state=' + stateVal
  });
```

let me know if i am approaching it the right way..

Comment: Add `method="get"`, `action="page"` and a `target` attribute to your form, and you don’t need JavaScript … (and will therefor be much less likely to get caught in any popup blocker.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript to do this.

Simply add an `action` attribute with the URL and set the `method` attribute to `GET` (this will append the named field values as a query string).

```
<form action="<yourURL>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" placeholder="XXX">
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="XXX">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

NOTE: You'll need `name` attributes on your fields.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjh7wkj4/

Comment: Is there any way to pass a URL parameter to test on a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

No need any jQuery/javascript to do that, form tag is providing those functionality. Adding action and method (GET) attributes will give you the results what you expect.

```
<form action="<target_url>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" placeholder="XXX">
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="XXX">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```