# Changing href destination depending on input value

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I'm currently creating a donation form that allows for custom donations. My donation plugin detects the ?amount= url value and pre-selects it when the user lands on the donation page.

So far this is the html input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="7.00" name="singular" id="singular">
<a href="http://example.com/donate/?amount=" id="myLink" class="et_pb_button dnt">Donate</a>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$('#singular').on('input', function() {
  $('#myLink').prop('href', this.value);
});
```

When I click the actual donate button however, it adds the inputted value to the end of the current pages url, e.g: `http://example.com/page1/7` instead of taking you to `http://example.com/donate/?amount=7`.

I know it must be something stupidly simple. How can I fix this?

**Update on Error**

When loading the https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js the script suggested works fine.

But when I remove that jquery.min and load the full wordpress core jquery (version: 1.12.4) Chrome Inspect display the following error:

*Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function*

**Update 2.0**

I couldn't find an easy way to solve the error but in my searches I did find a solution that is non javascript dependent if anyone else is interested in doing this:

[How to pass input field values as a url query string that will be opened on click of a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241407/how-to-pass-input-field-values-as-a-url-query-string-that-will-be-opened-on-clic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're overwriting the `href` attribute of the link by the value of the input. This makes the `href` of the anchor relative to current page's URL, and that's why it navigates to the URLs, such as `http://example.com/page1/7`.

You will need to change the query parameter with the value of the input box.

One way to do this is to use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API to change the `amount` query param instead. See the following snippet.

```js
$('#singular').on('input', function() {
  var href = new URL($('#myLink').prop('href'));
  href.searchParams.set('amount', this.value);
  $('#myLink').prop('href', href.toString())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="7.00" name="singular" id="singular">
<a href="http://example.com/donate/?amount=" id="myLink" class="et_pb_button dnt">Donate</a>
```